# Get list of files at path swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, nsfilemanager

Just trying to make a for..in loop for files in the local app folder

```
let filemanager:NSFileManager = NSFileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumeratorAtPath(NSHomeDirectory())
for filename in files!
{
    println(filename)
}
```

But it says Type 'NSDirectoryEnumerator' doesn't conform to protocol SequenceType.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this may be possible by implementing an extension to NSFileManager that implements the SequenceType protocol. But you could easily convert your code to using a while loop:

```
let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager()
let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: NSHomeDirectory())
while let file = files?.nextObject() {
    print(file)
}
```

Comment: Regarding implementing SequenceType to do this using your for loop, there is a good example here: http://natashatherobot.com/swift-conform-to-sequence-protocol/

Comment: How to get file from existing folder (i.e Download)

Comment: where to store file(.zip) while import(share extension) from gmail to application?